# Indy HTTP(s) reverse proxy

Tags: delphi, tcp, proxy, indy, socks

I'm trying to create a HTTP(s) proxy server that will act like this:

Browser configured to use proxy on 127.0.0.1:1080. On this port, I need to have a server (TIdTCPServer?) that will pass data coming to a client, that is connected on this same server (maybe into another port to make things easier). The client need to be connected, and not serving connection because of possible NAT restrictions.

The idea is that the client will execute the requests and send back to the server, which should send to the browser.

Browser > connect to local server > send to client connected which make the request

I thought about IdHTTPProxy, but no idea on how to pass request to a client, and client execute, gets back the data to the server / browser.

I read about TIdMappedPortTCP, but looks like this should connect into another host/port, and in my case the client can't receive connections.

Comment: None of Indy's proxy components support the type of model you are looking for. I would suggest studying the source for `TIdHTTPProxyServer` and replace its internal `TIdTCPClient` connections with `TIdTCPServer`/`TIdSimpleServer` connections.

Comment: I'm thinking to try using TIdTCPServer / TIdTCPClient, implementing Socks5. And doing all HTTP requests on TCP level.